# map of map of set of maps initialisation error

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, std, stdmap

I am trying to initialise a deeply nested hash which essentially has an integer key pointing to a set , where each value in set should point to another map of string and structure.

it doesn't compile with no matching function to insert error.

Can you please help me in initialising the below hash,

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>



struct values
{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    values():a("milepost"),b("dummyval"){};
    values( std::string ab, std::string bc)
    {
        a=ab;
        b=bc;

    };
};

typedef  std::map<std::string,values> my_waysides ;

typedef  std::map <int, std::set<std::string> > groups;

typedef  std::map <std::string,my_waysides> myData;

typedef  std::map <std::string,my_waysides> myData;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

   std::map<int, std::map< std::set<std::string>,std::map<std::string,my_waysides>> > stringStringMap;

   my_waysides  m_wayside1,m_wayside2,m_wayside3;

   myData data1;
   data1.insert( std::make_pair("7893" , m_wayside1) );


    stringStringMap.insert(std::make_pair(1,std::make_pair("ET", data1)));

    stringStringMap.insert(std::make_pair(1,std::make_pair("PT", data1)));

}
```

DataSet ex:

```
   1=>PT=>"789235"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   1=>PT=>"789234"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   1=>PT=>"789237"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   1=>PT=>"789238"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   1=>ET=>"789235"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   1=>ET=>"789234"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   1=>ET=>"789237"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   1=>ET=>"789238"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   2=>PT=>"789235"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   2=>PT=>"789234"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   2=>PT=>"789237"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   2=>PT=>"789238"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   2=>ET=>"789235"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   2=>ET=>"789234"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   2=>ET=>"789237"=>{milepost,dummyval}
   2=>ET=>"789238"=>{milepost,dummyval}
```

Thanks
Tejas

Comment: std::mapception

Comment: Regardless of fixing whatever syntax error you may have, there is a more significant problem here: `map<int, map<set<string>, map<string, std::map<std::string,values>>>>` is almost certainly a design mistake.  I recommend posting this along with a description of the problem you are trying to solve, here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - then add a comment on this question with a link to that post.  I'm sure we can help you work out a better structure.

Comment: @JohnZwinck : i have posted the dataset and Iam trying to create an xml out of this output . Iam posting the sub problem first

Comment: @LearningCpp: I see you've posted it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158899/initiate-a-map-of-map-of-set-of-maps-how-to-make-each-value-of-a-map-of-int - but you made the mistake of again discussing syntax errors, when what I think you ought to discuss there is more like "Here is the problem I am trying to solve and here is the data structure I intend to use - is this reasonable?"

Comment: @JohnZwinck  that's the issue , Iam just not able to insert and trying to get success, please advice improvement in this if possible

Answer (score 0):

A `std::map<key, value>` stores nodes with `std::pair<const key, value>`.

You are likely missing one or more `const` when building the pairs.

Comment: Does this not look right. std::map<int, std::map< std::set<std::string>,std::map<std::string,my_waysides>> > stringStringMap . The example dataset is also posted

Comment: The map declarations look correct, the problem with the insert is that you try to insert pairs with a non-const key, but `insert` expects `map::value_type`which is `pair<const key, value>`.